# Unity3d parsed Json file is printing Null values

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

My guess is, I am either having problems with my class structures or I am having problems with my json file itself. I've looked at plenty of examples of how to read the file, and I think that's okay. My problem is that I cannot print any data out of this structure. Either it prints zeros only, or I have an error attempting to print.

Here's a snippet of my json file.

```
{
    "0":{
        "0":[
            "56_Tele",
            "Castle Spire",
            0,
            21
        ],
        "1":[
            "44_Reflecto",
            "Did you remember?",
            1,
            18
        ],
        "2":[
            "55_ShipPiece",
            "Salvation",
            1,
            21
        ],
        "3":[
            "36_Jump",
            "Saving",
            2,
            11
        ]
    }
}
```

And here's the class that reads in the json file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class DataManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset json_data;

    //[System.Serializable]
    public class WorldData
    {
        public uint WorldId;
        public WorldSceneIds[] Scenes;
    }

    //[System.Serializable]
    public struct WorldSceneIds
    {
        public uint SceneId { get; set; }
        public WorldSceneData[] WorldSceneData { get; set; }
    }

    //[System.Serializable]
    public class WorldSceneData
    {
        public string SceneName { get; set; }
        public string LevelName { get; set; }
        public uint MapXCoord { get; set; }
        public uint MapYCoord { get; set; }
    }

    private void Start()
    {

        WorldData idstruct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorldData>(json_data.text);
        Debug.Log(idstruct);
        Debug.Log(idstruct.Scenes[0].SceneId);
    }

}
```

I've tried changing the json file and the structures I am reading it into. I tried reading different fields from the structure that I've loaded in, all are malformed.

Comment: Classes should be serializable and only use fields. You can use properties adorned with `[field:SerializeField]` but each field name will be prepended with `k__BackingField` in the JSON.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that these classes will be serialized **by value** which means that you will lose the **by reference** nature of classes.

Comment: Last, haven't tested your code, but there appears to be some kind of cyclic reference between IDs and DATAs, the serializer is kinda primitive and might choke on these, i.e. better review your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your array to a class

```
    WorldData[] idstruct = JObject.Parse(json)
        .Properties()
        .Select(o => new WorldData
        {
            WorldId = Convert.ToUInt32(o.Name),
            Scenes = ((JObject)o.Value)
                           .Properties()
                           .Select(i => new JObject
                           {
                           ["SceneId"] = Convert.ToUInt32(i.Name),
                           ["WorldSceneData"] =
                           new JObject(
                           i.Value.Select((i, v) => new JProperty(v.ToString(), i)))
                           }.ToObject<WorldSceneIds>())
                           .ToArray()
        }).ToArray();

    //test
     uint sceneId = idstruct[0].Scenes[0].SceneId;
```

and fix the classes

```
public class WorldData
    {
        public uint WorldId  { get; set; }
        public WorldSceneIds[] { get; set; }
    }

public class WorldSceneIds
{
    public uint SceneId { get; set; }
    public WorldSceneData WorldSceneData { get; set; }
}

public class WorldSceneData
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public string SceneName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string LevelName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public uint MapXCoord { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3")]
    public uint MapYCoord { get; set; }
}
```

or using dictionaries

```
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, WorldSceneData>> idstructDict = JObject
    .Parse(json)
    .Properties()
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => ((JObject)o.Value).Properties()
    .ToDictionary(v => v.Name, i => new JObject(
                           i.Value
                            .Select((v, i) => new JProperty(i.ToString(), v)))
                           .ToObject<WorldSceneData>()));

    //tests

    sceneId = Convert.ToUInt32(idstructDict["0"].Keys.ToArray()[1]); // "1"

    var sceneName = idstructDict["0"].Values.ToArray()[0].SceneName; // "56_Tele"
```